# Why tcpdump captures many packets with "(tcp-syn) != 0" but not with "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn) != 0"

Tags: networking, tcpdump

I want to capture the initial handshake of a UDP connection between my computer and a VPN server. For that I'm using `tcpdump` but I don't understand why :

```
tcpdump dst port 1194 and "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn) != 0"
```

Won't capture anything, while

```
tcpdump dst port 1194 and "(tcp-syn) != 0"
```

captures multiple packets during the connection when it's supposed to capture only the first SYN packet initiating the handshake.

What is `tcp[tcpflags]` used for ?

Comment: port suggests you are using OpenVPN which should use UDP, not TCP, and UDP is connectionless so I suspect SYN does not apply. I think OpenVPN can use UDP but that should not be default. Maybe this will give you ideas for further investigation.

Answer (score 3):

1. `tcp[tcpflags]` is a variable storing the TCP flags (bits) on currently captured TCP packet. `tcp-syn` is a constant with zeroes everywhere except the bit corresponding to TCP SYN packet. Thus:

   ```
   tcpdump dst port 1194 and "(tcp-syn) != 0"
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
   tcpdump dst port 1194 and 1 = 1
   ```
2. UDP protocol is simpler and doesn't have these flags - there is no SYN, ACK, etc. in UDP traffic. As a result there is no real handshake you can capture without inspecting content of the UDP packets.
3. If the VPN communication really is running over UDP. Then first rule won't capture the "handshake" because it applies to TCP packets only. Second will capture it but along with everything directed to port 1194 - both TCP and UDP.